# Proportional Date axis in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an Excel file with two variables.  I'm using the x axis as a date variable.  That column of data is formatted as a number->Date.  But when I insert a graph of it, it treats the x axis as a categorical variable (in other workds, each data point has the same width and is not proportional).

I have looked at [Datetime X-axis in Excel with proportional distances between value points](https://superuser.com/questions/1494221/datetime-x-axis-in-excel-with-proportional-distances-between-value-points)

It suggests several things, all of which I have done, viz.:

- axis-options  ->  date axis    Done (see 2 pictures)

Axis is date:

[image: Axis is date]

Other setting for axis is date:

[image: Other setting for axis is date]

- Make it a scatter plot with lines     Done

I would attach the spreadsheet, but I evidently cannot

The date column is formatted as Date type
[image: date column formatting]

Here is the picture in response to the request to post results of isText() and isNumber():
[image: isText() and isNumber()]

Comment: thanks for posting results of the formulas. They look correct. However having 1/0/1900... as axis values clearly indicates Excel can't interpret your dates correctly. Unfortunately without having your workbook I can't tell more. What you still can try: create a new workbook and see the behaviour. Double check source data of chart.

Answer (score 1):

Try TYPING the date in format like this
2022-11-07
And try notice if excel now actually sees this as a date rather than text.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely issue is that your data - although looks like dates - is actually text.

The easiest way to check whether Excel recognize your dates, is to change date format. If format is changing according to your settings, that's ok, otherwise Excel consider them as text.

Only dates stored properly are managed correctly in charts and pivot tables.

Comment: I should have showed that.  No, the dates are formatted as Date type.   I have attached picture of the formatting to the question

Comment: Can you post screenshot also with different date formatting setting of the same data?

Comment: also please run ISTEXT() and ISNUMBER() functions with one of your date cells as input and post the result.

Comment: I can only paste that into my original question.  I cannot paste it here.

As for your request: "Can you post screenshot also with different date formatting setting of the same data?"  I apologize, but I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: @dsa42 when people ask you to add things, they always mean "in your original question". We know pics can't go in comments, and that's on purpose. The goal is to continue to improve your question.